# How to configure a /27 subnet on vlan Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, vlan, subnet

I have a dedicated server running Centos 7.
I purchased a /27 subnet from my hosting provider. They said:
"Your /27 subnet should be acceptable over vlan-interface with tag 18."

I asked them if they could configure the interface for me but they said they are not familiar with my OS. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this either. Everything I've tried has bricked my network interface.

Any help or step in the right direction is really appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Here is my current network interface config: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1`

```
DEVICE=eno1
HWADDR=xx:c4:xx:c4:xx:14
IPV6INIT=no
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=162.x.x.23
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
GATEWAY=216.x.x.1
PREFIX=32
DEFROUTE=yes
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=1.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the /27 subnet has a

```
NETMASK=255.255.255.224
```

To make a 802.1q VLAN subinterface, you need to simply use a corresponding name, and tag that it is a VLAN:

```
DEVICE=eno1.18
VLAN=yes
```

Put all of this into `/etc/sysconfig/network-scrips/ifcfg-eno1.18`, together with other statements (IP address and so on).

Also create a `ifcfg-eno1` file, to have a *base* interface of this VLAN subinterface configured. Don't set up any IP address on it:

```
DEVICE=eno1
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
```

This is described in [the reference for RHEL7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configure_802_1q_vlan_tagging_using_the_command_line), which is suitable for CentOS 7 (and for Oracle Linux 7) as well.